# Python 3 - series start date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I downloaded a list of currencies from a website. All the prices start in 2018-01-01 except for one currency, which starts in 2015. How can I have that series starting in 2018 so I can chart them together from 2018.

I've tried `loc and datetime`, and nothing works. code below.

```
base_polo_url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair={}&start={}&end={}&period={}'
start_date = datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') # get data from the start of 2018
end_date = datetime.now() # up until today
period = 300 # pull daily data (300 seconds per day)

def get_crypto_data(poloniex_pair):
    '''Retrieve cryptocurrency data from poloniex'''
    json_url = base_polo_url.format(poloniex_pair, start_date.timestamp(), end_date.timestamp(), period)
    data_df = get_json_data(json_url, poloniex_pair)
    data_df = data_df.set_index('date')
    return data_df

altcoins = ['ETH','LTC','XRP','STR','DASH','SC','XMR','XEM','MAID']

altcoin_data = {}
for altcoin in altcoins:
    coinpair = 'BTC_{}'.format(altcoin)
    crypto_price_df = get_crypto_data(coinpair)
    altcoin_data[altcoin] = crypto_price_df
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter data before 2018 you can simply do

```
data_df = date_df.loc[start_date:]
```

Edit : for that you need a datetime index :

```
data_df.index = pd.to_datetime(data_df.index)
```